# How to crack this $T_r$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $$T_r=\frac{(-1)^{r-1}(r^2+r-9).3^{r-1}}{(r+1)!}$$

I need to prove that $$S_n=-2-\frac{(-1)^n 3^n (n-2)}{(n+1)!}$$

But I need a hint on how to crack that $T_r$. I mean, , Obvious answer should be partial fractions but I don't see how to apply that over here. Please guide.

Edit: I'm asking a way to to get a sophisticated general term i.e. $T_r$ , as for $S_n$, that ain't a priority right now. I need help in Expressing $T_r$ as a sum of two fractions? like we do with partial fractions.

Comment: Can we assume that $S_n=\Sigma_1^n T_r$  ?

Comment: Yes, it is so @tomi

Comment: Try to use induction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a telescoping sum.

> We obtain for $n\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=1}^nT_r&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{r-1}(r^2+r-9)3^{r-1}}{(r+1)!}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-3)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-3)^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(-3)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}-\sum_{r=3}^{n+2}\frac{(-3)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{(-3)^0}{0!}+\frac{(-3)^1}{1!}-\frac{(-3)^{n}}{n!}-\frac{(-3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=-2-\frac{(-3)^n(n-2)}{(n+1)!}\\
> &=S_n
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we note that $r^2+r-9=r(r+1)-9$ and split the sum accordingly.
- In (2) we shift the index of the right sum by $2$ to start with $r=3$.
- In (3) we see that terms with $2\leq r\leq n$ cancel due to telescoping, leaving terms with $r=0,1,n+1$ and $r=n+2$.